# fabric.js canvas unable to select element first time

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

fabric.js canvas library does not give option to select element once reload the page than it allows to select element. can somebody please help.

the canvas is being called using standard method this is the code

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1', { selection: true });

        var text = new fabric.Text("Hello World", { left: 100, top: 100 });
        canvas.add(text);
        canvas.selection = true;
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
```

Tried to include selection true but does not work.

Comment: Does this work for you http://jsfiddle.net/YpBk6/ ?

Comment: yes this is working.. but not sure what is problem on my end.. it does not work

Comment: Could you modify my fiddle to reflect any differences you have? I'm guessing it's about _when_ your code runs (notice the `onDomready` option I used) but it's just a hunch.

Comment: i have code like this. http://jsfiddle.net/YpBk6/1/

Comment: Works for me (after I included jQuery in the fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/YpBk6/2/

Comment: added canvas.calcOffset(); before canvas.renderAll() and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added canvas.calcOffset(); before canvas.renderAll() 
and it solved the problem

Now it is loading selection controls